# Confusion in using the preposition "to"

Tags: prepositions

> He was elected Chairman **to** the board.

Or

> He was elected Chairman **of** the board.

Which one is correct?

Comment: **He was elected AS the Chairman OF the board** is correct.

Comment: @bella what is the reasoning here? I thought of is used to show the relation to something. Why to is used here?

Comment: I can't point out the exact reason, that's why I didn't add it in the answers, Sorry :(

Comment: @BellaSwan you don’t need *the* before *chairman* . *As* can also be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

["Chairman of the board"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chairman%5C) is a title. Disambiguation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chairman_of_the_Board_(disambiguation)).

Your confusion may come from the similarity with other uses:

> He was assigned **to** the team.

Here, the team is seen as one unit, and the new guy is seen still as an outsider, which needs to become a part of the team.

But in the "Chairman of the board", "of" is used in order to emphasize that the Chairman is not only related to the board, but also a member of it - from the first moment, after election. He may have been also a member of the board previously - and the just got a new title / position / responsibility.

Board = Board of directors.

Answer (score 1):

*Chairman of the board* is a **clearly defined** role, a **named position** within an organization.

> She was proclaimed **Queen**.
>
> He was elected **President**.
>
> She was made **CEO of the corporation**.
>
> He was elected **Chairman of the board**.